# Remove nested lists from parent list

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

Let's say I have the following list `data` and I want to make the list `flat_data`:

```
data = [[1, 2], 3, 4, [5, [6, 7]]]
flat_data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

What's the best way to do this?

Here's what I have so far but ideally I want everything stuffed into one function:

```
flat_data = []
def flatten_data(data):
    for i in data:
        if type(i) == list:
            flatten_data(i)
        else:
            flat_data.append(i)
    return flat_a

flatten_data(data)
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: try reducing...

Comment: What do you find deficient about your approach here? One tip: use `isinstance(i, list)` instead of `if type(i) == list`

Comment: Looks like the answer already exists out there. And thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga I realize now `instance` covers subclasses as well so it's better than `type`